# vpasolve More Unknowns than Equations => No Solutions

Tags: matlab, solver

I have 3 equations and 4 unknowns that I want to solve for. Of course there are solutions, but vpasolve doesnt return any, if I drop down to 3 eq and 3 unknowns, it works good. I know that with more unknowns I have pretty much infinite number of solutions, so how do I make it work in that case?

Here is my code:

```
syms x y z theta1 theta2 theta3 phi1

xEquation = x == cos(theta1)*cos(phi1) + cos(theta1 + theta2)*cos(phi1) + cos(theta1 + theta2 + theta3)*cos(phi1)
yEquation = y == cos(theta1)*sin(phi1) + cos(theta1 + theta2)*sin(phi1) + cos(theta1 + theta2 + theta3)*sin(phi1)
zEquation = z == sin(theta1) + sin(theta1 + theta2) + sin(theta1 + theta2 + theta3)

x = 2;
y = 1.5;
z = 0;
sol = vpasolve([eval(xEquation), eval(yEquation), eval(zEquation)], [theta1, theta2, theta3, phi1], [-pi pi; -pi pi; -pi pi; -pi pi;]);
```

That produces sol struct with 4 fields but they are empty, no solutions.

Comment: what are the solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solving m equations with n unknowns such as `m<n`, means some variables will be parameters that's depending on other variables.

For example

```
x-3y+z = 2
x-y+5z = 5
```

Let suppose `z` to be the parameter
To solve this in Matlab here is the code

```
syms x y z

eq1 = x-3*y+z ==2;
eq2 = x-y+5*z ==5;
sol = solve(eq1, eq2, x, y);
sol.x
sol.y
```

As you can see `z` been omitting in solve expression, which means it will be considered as the parameter
**The solution is**

```
sol.x = 13/2 - 7*z
sol.y = 3/2 - 2*z
```

- From the solution we can see that **`x, y and z` are not numerical
  values, so that's the reason you can not use `vpasolve`which
  stands for `Variable-precision arithmetic`**. *vpasolve gives a
  precision to numerical solution*
- Also since `x, y and z` are not numerical values you can not predefine
  a range for them, unless you fix `z` first

---

You may use `solve` to have a view of the solution set, here I consider `phi1` to the parameter, so omitted it in solve expression

```
syms x y z theta1 theta2 theta3 phi1
    
xEquation = 2 == cos(theta1)*cos(phi1) + cos(theta1 + theta2)*cos(phi1) + cos(theta1 + theta2 + theta3)*cos(phi1);
yEquation = 1.5 == cos(theta1)*sin(phi1) + cos(theta1 + theta2)*sin(phi1) + cos(theta1 + theta2 + theta3)*sin(phi1);
zEquation = 0 == sin(theta1) + sin(theta1 + theta2) + sin(theta1 + theta2 + theta3);
  
    
sol = solve(xEquation, yEquation, zEquation, theta1, theta2, theta3);
```

## Solution set

```
sol.theta1 = [-pi*(2*n - 1); pi*(2*m + 1); pi*k; pi*k]
sol.theta2 = [pi*(2*m + 1);  -pi*(2*n - 1);  -pi*(2*n - 1); z]
sol.theta3 = [pi*k; pi*k; pi*(2*m + 1); pi*(2*m + 1)] 
phi1 is the parameter
```

## First solution set

```
X = [sol.theta1(1); sol.theta2(1); sol.theta3(1); phi1]
X = [-pi*(2*n - 1); pi*(2*m + 1); pi*k; phi1]
```

There are 4 sets written accordingly to the above deductions

- `z` is the parameter, `k, m, n` are integer numbers which are mainly
  used for trigonometric functions periodicity
- If you set `z` in range `[-pi, pi]` you can adjust `k, m and n` to
  get valid solution in range `[-pi, pi]`.

## As you can see it's time costing

---

## Use `fmincon`

- Alternatively you can use **fmincon** to solve your problem
- I mainly minimize a constant function, fmincon will just give
  solutions that satisfy the constraints, here `ceq = 0`
- The interval of search `[-pi pi]` is transformed to `lb = -pi` and
  `ub = pi`
- I set the initial guess to `0`

## The code is as follow

```
t = 0:0.1:1;
x = 1.5 + 0.5 .* cos(8 .* pi .* t);
y = 1.5 + 0.5 .* sin(8 .* pi .* t); 
z = 1 .* t .* ones(size(x));

lb = -pi*ones(1, 4);
ub = -lb;

p0 = zeros(1,4);
sol = cell(1,length(t));

for i = 1:length(t)
    sol{i} = fmincon(@(p)0,p0,[],[],[],[],lb,ub,@(p)nonlincon(x(i),y(i), z(i), p(1), p(2), p(3), p(4)));


end


function [c, ceq] = nonlincon(x,y, z, theta1, theta2, theta3, phi1)

    c = [];
    ceq(1) = cos(theta1)*cos(phi1) + cos(theta1 + theta2)*cos(phi1) + cos(theta1 + theta2 + theta3)*cos(phi1)-x;
    ceq(2) = cos(theta1)*sin(phi1) + cos(theta1 + theta2)*sin(phi1) + cos(theta1 + theta2 + theta3)*sin(phi1)-y;
    ceq(3) = sin(theta1) + sin(theta1 + theta2) + sin(theta1 + theta2 + theta3)-z;
end
```

## Solution

**Second set of solution when `t = 0.1` is `sol{2}`**

```
sol{2}.(1) = pheta1
sol{2}.(2) = pheta2
sol{2}.(3) = pheta3
sol{2}.(4) = phi1
```

You can follow same logic to find solution at different time t

> The Entire solution

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the lengthy explanation, I don't really understand how fmincon works, but obviously it works. However, I have one issue with it, I have to solve these equations for multiple values of x, y and z, and each consecutive solution should be as close as possible to the previous solution.
t = 0:0.1:1;
x = 1.5 + 0.5 .* cos(8 .* pi .* t);
y = 1.5 + 0.5 .* sin(8 .* pi .* t);
z = 1 .* t .* ones(size(x));
If I use these values for x,y,z I still get solutions, but they are way off. I managed to fix this issue with vpasolve and it works perfectly when eqns = unknowns, but...

Comment: Alright accordingly to what you said vpasolve will give you hard time, that's what I try to show you above, the right tool is ```fmincon```. I update the answer according to the time changing ```x, y, z```. My answer is quite long, you can read about ```fmincon``` first, then maybe open chat discussion if you have question

Comment: Thanks Adam, I managed to do the looping by myself, but as i said the problem was that the solutions that I get when I do this are way, each consecutive solution must be as close as possible to the previous solution, for example if theta1(1) is 0.5 then theta1(2) must be as close as possible to 0.5. Anyway, i figured it out, I did it the same way I did it with vpasolve, I recalculate lb and ub after each solution, so I have this lb = sol(n, :) - step; ub = sol(n, :) + step; inside the loop, where step is the allowed deviation. I would really like to talk to you about fmincon :)

Comment: So after I implemented this change, I am now getting solutions that are closer together, I have yet to implement it in my main code and see how it actually works, but so far so good. How do I open chat with you?